# How does is the blend interaction functionality implemented?

Tags: wpf, blend, interaction

Out of curiosity, I'd like to know how the `Blend` interaction (such as in the following example) functionality works behind the hood.

1. Is `Interaction` some kind of attached property?
2. How do you have elements of a control using a different namespace?

Does anyone know of a tutorial or something that goes through an implementation of something like this? i.e how you would do this yourself with just the barebones wpf framework and no other frameworks

```
<TextBox>
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                    ...
              </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Interaction` is the class, `Triggers` the attached property, access is always like that for attached properties, they can be set on any control. I would recommend reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Comment: ah, thankyou. I wasn't aware of that syntax for attached properties, Ive only ever seen the attribute syntax. Makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

1 - The `System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction` Class defines 2 attached properties:

- Triggers
- Behaviors

2 - Those are not "elements of a control", those are [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), which can be applied to any UI element regardless of the namespace.